# Nexus 10 stuck in bootloop after Lollipop flash no ADB and no Fastboot

Tags: boot-loop, bootloader, fastboot, samsung-nexus-10, 5.0-lollipop

So .... I flashed the *mantaray-lrx21p* image from [Nexus Factory Images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#mantaraylrx21p) on my Nexus 10 (16GB Wifi) and it's stuck in a bootloop.

No problem, I thought, I can get into fastboot and fix it, right? Maybe do a wipe and try again? Yeah, not so fast. I get the bootloader screen, but the only option is 'Start' which just boots into the system that bootloops.

That's OK, I'll just use fastboot to wipe it. Nope. Fastboot doesn't detect a device.

I've tried both ADB and fastboot on Mac & Linux. Same issue.

Ideas?

Comment: How long did you wait? I had to wait >5 minutes for my Nexus 7 2012 just now. It's working fine.

Comment: Over 25 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to enter the bootloader with the *USB cable plugged in*. Once I unplugged the USB cable and held `power + Vol Up + Vol Down` it booted into bootloader and I was able to get fastboot connected.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue right now. fastboot oem lock didn't find the device.
Disconnected the device from USB and held the power button for 10s to reset. Booted like a charm afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this exact same issue. I'm going to try flashing 4.4 again and see if I can at least get it up and running again.

Edit: I was able to get it booting my locking the bootloader. (run fastboot oem lock from bootloader)

Comment: I can't get fastboot to detect it so I can't flash 4.4 again ... or wipe.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same on my Nexus 7 2012 just now.

Flashed the factory image, device remained stuck at the boot logo. went to bootloader and did "fastboot erase cache" along with "fastboot erase userdata". Still the same never ending boot logo.

Put the device back into bootloader mode again, ran "fastboot oem lock", restarted and the device quickly started loading the OS as normal. Currently staring at "Android is Upgrading...." .

locking the bootloader is a good way to go. you can then backup any data you want off the device if you didnt originally erase it all before running "fastboot oem unlock".

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and decided to turn it off and after it turned itself back on and fixed the problem. (So dont everyone freak out it might just need to be turned off really quick)

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue. Booted into download mode, and neither fasboot nor ADB see the device (MacOS 10.9). They are working for me on my Nexus 5, so it's not an ADB/fastboot driver issue or anything.